# Accessing the AJAX response and updating the table with new values

Tags: ajax, grails

I am confused with the handling of the response of the server, when submitting an AJAX request. What I would like to do, is an update of a table by clearing it and inserting the new ones.

The following code of the controller gives a resonse to an ajax request, triples is a list:

```
def resultsAjax = {
    def triples = linkedDataService.getRemoteTriplesTable("Student4")
    render(template:'tripleResultsTable', model:[triples:triples])
}
```

This is the form:

```
<g:form action="results">
    <label for="id">Resource ID </label>
    <g:textField name="id" />
    <g:submitToRemote value="search"  update="resultsAjax"
                  url="[controller:'tripleProperty', action:'resultsAjax']"/>
 </g:form>
```

And the table below:

```
<g:render  id="resultsAjax" template="tripleResultsTable" model="${triples}"/>
```

How can I access the list that is responded from the server?

**EDIT:**

It works more or less, but strange thing is, that the table is not updated, but the new values are on top of the table...

[image]

The template is just this:

```
<g:each in="${triples}" status="i" var="tripleProperty">
<tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

    <td>${tripleProperty.property}</td>

    <td>${tripleProperty.value}</td>

</tr>
```

Does it need some more code than render(template..) to replace the values in the table?

Answer (score 1):

What does your tripleResultsTable.gsp template look like? You probably the model attribute to look like this

```
<g:render  id="resultsAjax" template="tripleResultsTable" model="${[triples:triples]}" />
```

Then in your template you can use

```
<g:each in="${triples}">...</g:each>
```

to ouput the TR/TD elements you want

cheers

Lee